Does Bravery feat makes you immune to Frightened 1?
The last part of Bravery feat description is this:

In addition, anytime you gain the frightened condition, reduce its value by 1.

Does this mean that Frightened 1 gets reduced to 0, thus rendering it ineffective immediately? Or is there a general minimum 1?

Not completely, but mostly!
There are a variety of effects in the game that prevent the reduction of Frightened below 1 - Auras of Dread and what have you. Any of these will prevent Bravery from functioning. Other than that, yes, a Fighter above level 3 can not simply be Frightened 1 - it takes an application of Frightened 2 or better to stick to them.
